# How to translate character

Tags: character-identification

How to translate character on image below?

[image]

Comment: 禄, salary/happiness.

Answer (score 4):

The character 祿 has two meanings:

1. Good fortunes.
2. Government salary (in the imperial Chinese government).

Which one you'd want to translate it to depends on the context.

Comment: I wouldn't imagine it's the second one though...

Comment: @user3306356 it still comes up in good wishes and sayings regarding rewards, raises, etc; e.g. 利祿薰心 and 無功不受祿